# how would i make a global leaderboard on roblox that is multiple stats in this hierarchy, best to worst: generals, soldiers, trainees, weapons,funding

Tags: roblox, leaderboard

i know how to make a leaderboard that is about 1 stat but nobody says about making one that finds the best out of multiple stats. (This is a button simulator type game where funding is cash that you get 1 per sec and all the other stats are multipliers for the one before.) only funding is a part of leaderstats but everything else isnt on leaderstats just in the player. i alreayd made a datastore and leaderstats script and everything

i only know how to make leaderboard about 1 stat not multiple

Comment: So to clarify, you want to make a leaderboard where multiple stats are displayed? If that is the case, you just have to put multiple values inside of the `leaderstats` folder inside the player.

Comment: no like a physical leaderboard not the leaderstats

Comment: Ah! okay. Then you can use a billboard with a surface gui with text on it and update it with information from the datastore. SurfaceGUIs allow you to put editable text on physical objects just like a screen gui.